# set-input-method in emacs and colour highlighting

Tags: emacs

I am using set-input-method in emacs (with (set-input-method "portuguese-prefix") in my .emacs file). I write notes on Portuguese grammar in a file opened in the org-mode. The file has both English and Portuguese in it. I notice that some words are highlighted yellow or orange, but I don't see the logic. If it is because some Portuguese word is interpreted as a wrongly spelled English word, then I also see many other Portuguese words that don't change their colour. Could someone explain what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: I guess(only a guess) you should add Portuguese dictionary to aspell dictionaries

Comment: I already have the Brazilian Portuguese aspell dictionary installed. Is there some way to make sure it is activated when I change the set input method? But because the file has both English and Portuguese, I would want both dictionaries to be enabled.